# Find file with smallest 4-digit-number

Tags: bash, files, find, regular-expression

I have many, many files of the form [`[a-zA-Z]+\d\.\d{2}\_\d.\d{4}.end`](http://regexr.com/3fhkr) and want to find the file(s) with the smallest 4 digit number right before `.end`. (in case of collision I want all files)

How can you do that using Bash? `sort` alone doesn't work, obviously, due to lexicographic ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bash, `find` and the `sort` `-t|--field-separator` and `-k|--key` options:

`find_files.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
first_file=$(find . -iname '*.end' | sort -t '.' -k 4.1 | head -1)
IFS='.'
fields=($first_file)
unset IFS
find . -iname "*${fields[3]}.end"
```

The `-k|--key` options expects a `KEYDEF` of the form *field_number***.***character_number*. When `-t|--field-separator` is in effect, the field numbers are calculated based on the specified separator (in this case `.`) rather than a whitespace.

We then extract the wanted pattern from the first file using Bash's [input-field separator](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS), and search the directory with `find` again for files matching that pattern in case several files share the same 4-digit number.

**Example:**

```
$ ls -1
abc0.03_1.1921.end
def0.03_9.0311.end
ghi0.03_1.1966.end
jkl1.04_1.1916.end
mno2.04_4.9540.end
pab9.04_1.1994.end
uvx7.04_3.2002.end
yyy1.05_8.0311.end
zzz4.04_1.2097.end
$ ./find_files.sh
./yyy1.05_8.0311.end
./def0.03_9.0311.end
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU tools, you could do something like:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}_[0-9]\.[0-9]{4}\.end' -print0 |
  awk -v RS='\0' -F . '
    NR == 1 || $(NF-1) < min {files=$0; min = $(NF-1); next}
    $(NF-1) == min {files = files "\n" $0}
    END {if (NR) print files}'
```

That's an example of a common pattern: we print the list of matching files NUL-delimited (as NUL is the only character  that can't occur in a file path) and process that output with `awk` where the record separator has been set to NUL (not all `awk` implementations support that though).

The *field separator* is set to `.`. `NF` is the number of fields, so `$(NF-1)` is the last before last field. `awk` finds the lowest number by comparing that with the last known value, and stores the corresponding files in the  `files` `awk` variable.

As we store the list newline-separated as opposed to NUL separated, that's only intended for user output. If you wanted to post-process it reliably, you'd want to use NUL (`"\0"` in awk) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` has `-t` and `-k`, which would allow you to sort based on one of the dot-separated parts of the file name, which should do it in this case.

```
-t, --field-separator=SEP
    use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

-k, --key=KEYDEF
    sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
```

(quote from [the man page of GNU sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html).)

Comment: Note that while `-k`/`-t` are standard, the long options are GNU extensions (now also supported by the sort of some BSDs though for compatibility with GNU `sort`). Using `sort -t . -k ...` can only be used here if those `.end` files are located in directories that don't contain dot or newline characters.

Comment: Yah, I forgot to add the link to the quote. And yes, I assumed the simple case where the files are in a single list/directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -le '
   for ( grep { /^[a-zA-Z]+\d\.\d{2}\_\d.\d{4}\.end$/ } <*.end> ) {
      ($n) = /(\d{4})\.end$/;
      $min //= $n;
      $n <= $min and $min = $n, push @{$h{$min}}, $_;
   }
   print for @{$h{$min}};
'
```

`<*>` collects all the relevant files using the globbing syntax, out of which, the proper syntax files shall be selected by the `for`.

Inside the `for` we first extract the last 4 digits to determine & compare it against the running `minimum` and if found , pushed onto a hash.

At the end, we simply print the contents of the hash with the key `$min`.